# How to add marker positions to audio metadata in ffmpeg?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

By "marker positions" I mean adding metadata that refers to a specific time in the audio.

I could add an outline of the audio in the metadata comments, but that's technically just normal text, which isn't what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about are often referred to as cue points. These markers are saved in a "cue sheet" which is a separate file that contains them. These cue sheets are recognized by several audio players.

You don't mention what format you want to add marker positions - and the only format that I know that have them built in are iTunes audio book files. They call them "index markers" and I don't know of any available tools that support them.

Comment: [BWF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_Wave_Format) store them as well. Pro audio editing apps should read the cue points.

Answer (score 1):

`WAV` files support storing cue markers in a chunk type of `'cue '`.  I know that Adobe's Audition will read and write these.  There are other formats that Audition reads which also have marker support.

`FFMpeg` has added support for `wav` cue markers, [FFmpeg Ticket 8872](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8872)